# VBA auto filter cannot choose the range

Tags: excel, vba, select, filter, range

I have the problem with auto filter in VBA.

I have the worksheet and have auto filter from cell A10 to cell M10. There are 200 rows in the worksheet.

After I copy and paste the  new data on it. The last data is on row 140. Every time the number of rows of data is different.

Then I want to delete the blanks row from 141 to 199.

But the problem is the auto filter only can choose the data range from row 11 to row 140. It can not include the blank rows.

I try to clear filter and set up the filter again. Afterwards, I delete all the rows until end of the sheet.

Could any one can help to solve it ?

Appreciated.
Joe

Answer (score 0):

Try using a dynamic count to find the last used row.

Example code:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
    
'clear any filters on "Summary" worksheet
If Worksheets("Summary").FilterMode Then Worksheets("Summary").ShowAllData

'reset used range (remove blank rows at the end of data)
Worksheets("Summary").UsedRange.Calculate

'count used rows
LastRow = Sheets("Summary").Cells(Sheets("Summary").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'filter for smaller than -81 from column H (8)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("$A$1:$J$" & LastRow).AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:="<=-81"
```

Comment: Hi XLmatters, why use  smaller than -81?

Comment: @JoeChan "-81" was used as just an example filter.  You can set your own Criteria value.

Comment: ThxXL. I got it